# Modal bootstrap is displayed behin an html object

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, silverlight, bootstrap-modal

I have a silverlight page in which I want to add a modal bootstrap. My problem is that the modal is displayed behind the silverlight page.
I saw that this can be happening because modal div is not isolated from the rest of your code, but in my case it is in the bottom of the code. Here is the source code[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the bootstrap CSS file increase the zindex if you have included a CDN. The use `.modal{z-index:300}`. Increase the 300

Comment: If your creating the style make sure that the style comes after the bootstrap style